# Turn (rotate) it that way, this way (toward you,toward me)

Tags: word-usage

My friend and I are standing across from each other (with a stool in the middle and a clamp stand on top of it, with a pendulum suspended from it; not in the image though....) 
[image]

Me can move the part that hold on to things like a burette. It can be done by loosening the screw. My friend was rotating it toward my direction (clockwise)  and I told her to rotate it in her direction.  Is it okay to use:

> Turn (or rotate)it that way.  (While talking and moving my hand to tell her)

Or should it be:

> Turn it your way.
>
> Turn it toward you. (And should it be rotate or turn?)

And for example,  if the screw had to be turned clockwise, (I.e my direction)

> Turn it this way. (Will it sound okay while talking?)

Or

> Turn it my way.
>
> Turn it toward me.

Answer (score 1):

In colloquial language, all of these sentences are correct and understandable.

You seem to have been a bit caught up with using "turn" vs "rotate." As you can see [here](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/rotate), Thesaurus.com lists "turn" as a one of the synonyms of "rotate."

Just make sure that when you use "this" or "that," you are simultaneously pointing to what you mean by those words.

Answer (score 0):

All of your examples are correct. @jmrpink explained it very well.

English, like many languages, have multiple ways to say the same thing. It is fine whichever you choose because others will understand you regardless.